# Codeception "ErrorException array to string conversion" with Laravel and Lang::get()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, tdd, codeception

I've already opened an issue on [Codeception Github Repository](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1087) so if you want to stay update on there you're welcome.

By the way I'll explain my problem even here, maybe someone has got the solution.

Basically when you write a functional test in Codeception with the Laravel4 module it seems that you cannot "parse" any kind of view with the `Lang::get()` statement or the `trans()` helper inside it (both do the same job).

For example this

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('container')
<div>
 {{ Lang::get('path.to.lang.file') }}
</div>
@stop
```

Will raise an exception if you try to test with codeception. I found this bug with a simple registration form built with Bootstrap (for CSS and stuff) and with the use of `Lang::get()` for the localization, this future web app must be multilanguage so I need it.

I paste the full stack error here but you can find it even on the issue link.

```
1) Failed to edit a bunch of data from an actual company in LoginAndEditDataCept (/Users

/Ludo237/Projects/L4/app/tests/functional/LoginAndEditDataCept.php)
Can't be on page "/auth/login":
ErrorException: Array to string conversion (View: /Users/Ludo237/Project/L4/app/views/public/auth/login.blade.php)

Scenario Steps:
2. I am on page "/auth/login"
1. As a An authenticated user


  [ErrorException] Array to string conversion (View: /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/app/views/public/auth/login.blade.php)  

#0 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(41): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException))
#1 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(56): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Users/Ludo237/...', Array)
#2 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(134): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/Users/Ludo237/...', Array)
#3 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(102): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#4 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(76): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#5 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(43): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#6 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php(202): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#7 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1437): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#8 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(999): Illuminate\Routing\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#9 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(964): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(738): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(708): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php(81): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php(332): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client->doRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/InnerBrowser.php(68): Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->request('GET', '/auth/login')
#15 [internal function]: Codeception\Lib\InnerBrowser->amOnPage('/auth/login')
#16 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Step.php(125): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/TestCase/Shared/Actor.php(67): Codeception\Step->run()
#18 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Scenario.php(93): Codeception\TestCase\Cept->runStep(Object(Codeception\Step\Condition))
#19 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/app/tests/functional/FunctionalTester.php(523): Codeception\Scenario->runStep(Object(Codeception\Step\Condition))
#20 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/app/tests/functional/LoginAndEditACompanyDataCept.php(7): FunctionalTester->amOnPage('/auth/login')
#21 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/TestCase/Cept.php(64): require('/Users/Ludo237/...')
#22 [internal function]: Codeception\TestCase\Cept->testCodecept()
#23 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(951): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Codeception\TestCase\Cept), Array)
#24 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(817): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
#25 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(686): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
#26 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(753): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(Codeception\TestCase\Cept))
#27 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(675): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#28 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/PHPUnit/Runner.php(100): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#29 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php(153): Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner->doEnhancedRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult), Array)
#30 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php(162): Codeception\SuiteManager->run(Object(Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner), Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult), Array)
#31 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php(145): Codeception\Codecept->runSuite(Array, 'functional', 'LoginAndEditACo...')
#32 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php(149): Codeception\Codecept->run('functional', 'LoginAndEditACo...')
#33 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(252): Codeception\Command\Run->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(887): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(193): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Codeception\Command\Run), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#37 /Users/Ludo237/Projects/L4/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept(27): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#38 {main}
```

This is the file used by `login.blade.php` is very very very simple and it is located under `app/lang/en/common.php`

```
  <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Common Language Lines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    |
    */

    'date' => [
        'days' => [
            '1' => 'Monday',
            '2' => 'Tuesday',
            '3' => 'Wednesday',
            '4' => 'Thursday',
            '5' => 'Friday',
            '6' => 'Saturday',
            '7' => 'Sunday'
        ],
    ]

];
```

And this is the `login.blade.php` part that use the lang file.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="auth-box col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">{{ trans('common.date.days.1') }}</div>
        </div>
```

Is there anyone who solved this trouble?

Comment: What exactly do you pass as `path.to.lang.file`?

Comment: @deczo is a string that point to the app/lang/ directory for example
assuming that the app now sets the locale to app/lang/en
trans('views/auth.register.somemessage') points to app/lang/en/views/auth.php 

the auth.php is a simple array (like the defaults one)

Comment: `Lang::get()` may return an array instead of a string, so please paste that lang file as well as real `path.message` string.

Comment: @deczo question updated :D

Comment: Just a guess, but try to rename `date.days.monday` and the array also to `'monday' => 'Monday'`. If that won't help then `dd(Lang::get(...))` to check which array is returned instead of `'Monday'` string

Comment: It works because if I try to use the browser like with a normal navigation I can see the "Monday" word (like in other page) the problem occurs only when I launch the test with Laravel4 module. The weird part is that if I change the Laravel4 Module in codeception with the PhpBrowser IT WORKS U_U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, and I repeat **MAYBE**, I found the solution to the problem

It seems that you **MUST** specify all the parameters when you write down `{{ Lang::get() }}`

For example, taking my question, I've to correct all the statement from

`{{ trans('common.date.days.1') }}` or `{{ Lang::get('common.date.days.1') }}`

to

`{{ trans('common.date.days.1', [], 'en') }}`

but obviously this is the worst solution ever to be honest.

EDIT: 
Actually I've found the real solution and is not like the mess above...

Simply put inside `tests/functional/_bootstrap.php` this

```
App::setLocale('en');
```

:D